# The notation $ f \in C^0 ([0,T],X) $

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

In general, do the notation $$ f \in C^0 ([0,T],X) $$ imply that $\| f(t) \|_X  < \infty$ for any fixed $t \in [0,T]$? Or just means $\| f (t) \|_X$ is continuous on $[0,T]$? Here $X$ is like $L^p$ space or Sobolev space.

Comment: Possibly it means just continuous, unlike, for example, $C^1$ which means continuously differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is any sensible space, i.e. a Banach space, then a continuous $f$ sends the compact interval $[0,T]$ to a compact set, which is bounded, hence the $X$-norm of $f(t)$ is always finite.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then how it becomes if $[0,\infty)$ instead of $[0,T]$?

Comment: In the definition of $L^p$ or Sobolev spaces that I know, every element has finite norm, so what you ask would be obvious. Hence I assume you allow in your spaces also elements of infinite norm. But then you lose the completeness of the space, (it is not even Banach!) and I have no answer at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I think that this notation means $\| f(t) \|_X < \infty$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ and $\| f(t) \|_X$, the function of t, is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Is this suitable?